# Initialize parameters via yaml in ros2

Tags: ros, ros2, ardent, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to this [PR](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/488), we can now initialize parameters via yaml file. I edited the talker example to have the parameter client so I can see the changes in parameters, but when I try to load the parameters via this line as given in the PR comments

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker_with_params __params:=install/share/demo_nodes_cpp/talker_params.yaml
```

I get this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' 
what(): Failed to parse parameters install/share/demo_nodes_cpp/talker_params.yaml
```

anything I'm doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294601/initialize-parameters-via-yaml-in-ros2/) by [aarushg](https://answers.ros.org/users/35073/aarushg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2018-06-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Likely the syntax of the yaml file is not correct. Can you post its contents? It should have syntax as described here: https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/master/rcl_yaml_param_parser/README.md

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarushg](https://answers.ros.org/users/35073/aarushg/) on 2018-06-19**:
yes, thank you. I wasn't aware of this yaml syntax it works now.